# How do you join a column for shipment grid?

Tags: magento2, grid, shipment, data-provider

I've already been able to add my column to the `sales_order_shipment_grid`. Now it's time to join the data from another table so we can display it.

**Approach 1:**

Some articles online suggest adding a join to the Grid resource model using something like:

```
<virtualType name="ShipmentGridAggregator">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="joins" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="my_table" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="table" xsi:type="string">my_table</item>
                <item name="origin_column" xsi:type="string">their_column</item>
                <item name="target_column" xsi:type="string">my_column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="my_column" xsi:type="string">my_table.my_other_column</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

The problem with this (as far as I can tell), is that this is deprecated in favor of using UIComponents and DataProviders. The `ShipmentGridAggregator` is not used anywhere except for `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\GridPool`, which in itself is not used for anything useful.

**Approach 2:**

So, time to dig in deeper... The shipment grid uses a data source called  `sales_order_view_shipment_grid_data_source` this in turn is configured to use `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection`. This class doesn't have an `$_eventPrefix` so we can't use an observer to join our field.

**Aproach 3:**

We are able to inject a custom `FetchStrategyInterface` into the collection listed above, but this doesn't seem to be its intended purpose. Will probably make it problematic with other modules that need to do something similar.

**Approach 4:**

The current plan... Just do a before-plugin on `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection::load` and add the join to `getSelect()` ourselves.

Anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Review from: https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-columns-to-order-grid-in-admin-magento-2/

Create or edit

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module_Name]/etc/admin/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="sales_order_shipment_columns_[unique_name]"
                type="[Vendor]/[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Filename"/>
    </type>
```

Create File at

> /app/code/[Vendor]/[Module_Name]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Filename.php

```
namespace [Vendor]/[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
class Filename
{
   public static $table = 'sales_shipment_grid';
   public static $sales_order = 'sales_order';

   public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
   {
      if ($requestName == 'sales_order_shipment_grid_data_source' || $requestName == 'sales_order_view_shipment_grid_data_source') {
        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$table)) {
            $salesOrderTable = $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$sales_order);
            $collection
                ->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(
                    ['so' => $salesOrderTable],
                    "so.entity_id = main_table.order_id",
                    [
                        'so.column_name',
                    ]
                )
                ;
            return $collection;
        }
    }

    return $collection;
 }
}
```

Create file at

> /app/code/[Vendor]/[Module_Name]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_view_shipment_grid.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <columns name="sales_order_shipment_columns">
            <column name="column_name">
                <settings>
                    <filter>text</filter>
                    <label translate="true">Column Title</label>
                </settings>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </listing>
```

Create File at

> /app/code/[Vendor]/[Module_Name]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_shipment_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <columns name="sales_order_shipment_columns">
            <column name="column_name">
                <settings>
                    <filter>text</filter>
                    <label translate="true">Column Title</label>
                </settings>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </listing>
```